# Оператор switch в Java

Tags: java, switch

Я только перешел с плюсов на джаву, и у меня возник следующий вопрос: в switch можно "сравнивать" только константы? Нет ли другой возможности использовать НЕконстантные переменные? И если возникла такая ситуация, что нужно, например, сравнивать много перемен, то неужели придется использовать if else if else if else if...?
Спасибо!

Comment: можно проверять Map на contains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом нет необходимости. Вы всегда можете любое дискретное множество (и не обязательно условий) можете перечислить констастантами и их использовать в качестве условия перехода оператора switch.

Другими словами вы всегда можете определить функцию которая пронумерует вам ваше мнежество из нескольких if else.